# Spacing Error with \centering, \align*

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, align

I am writing this proof, but there seems to be something strange with a couple of the smaller commentary lines - they ended up centering and overlapping despite the fact that they are supposed to be separated with linebreaks:

[image]

Here is another example of another block with the correct formatting (only changes are `\align*` blocks and values between the braces):

[image]

Here is the source code with comments around the affected lines:

```
Prove that in any set of $n$ numbers, there exists at least one number less than or equal to the mean.
\begin{proof}[Proof.]
Assumption($\neg S$): all numbers in set S are greater than the mean.

Suppose set $S = \newset{x_{1}, x_{2},\dots,x_{n}}$. Then the mean is $\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}+\dots+x_{n}}{n}$.

If each $x_{i}, \forall i \in [1, n]$ is greater than the mean:
\begin{align*}
    x_{1} &> \frac{x_{1}+x_{2}+\dots+x_{n}}{n} \\
    x_{2} &> \frac{x_{1}+x_{2}+\dots+x_{n}}{n} \\
    &\vdots \\
    x_{n} &> \frac{x_{1}+x_{2}+\dots+x_{n}}{n} 
\end{align*}

Get the sum of both sides of the inequality, we get $\newset{x_{1}, x_{2},\dots,x_{n}} > \newset{x_{1}, x_{2},\dots,x_{n}}$. % affected line 
\centering\small{Contradiction: No number (and thus follows, set of numbers) is greater than itself.} \par % affected line
$\neg S$ (each element in set $S$ is greater than the mean) is clearly false; because of this, $S$ must be true.
\[\therefore \text{In a set of n numbers, there is at least one number less than or equal to the mean.}\]
\end{proof}
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to remedy it? Thanks!

Comment: please provide code as a complete small test document  but the construct `\centering\small` mid-paragraph is rather weird. `\centering` will apply from the start of the paragraph and apply to all following paragraphs in this scope. `\small` will set the baselineskip to small for the whole paragraph despite the text prior to that being large,  (the `{` following `\small` does nothing useful, as `\small` does not take an argument)

Comment: it's not clear what output you intended but perhaps replace `\centering\small{` by `\begin{center}\small`  and replace `} \par` by `\end{center}`